# Electron density of filled vs unfilled orbital

Tags: atomic-physics

I'm currently working on a project that involves calculating electron density maps of various orbitals, i.e. using radial and angular wave functions etc. and its got me thinking... Does the overall density distribution change when the orbital has one electron vs two? Is the density doubled because another electron has been added to the orbital?

Answer (score 1):

Orbitals are single particle solutions to the Hamiltonian. This means that it neglects the electron-electron interaction. So when you add another electron, orbitals no longer are the correct picture. What we will see is a linear combination of all possible orbitals (as they form a basis). Thus the over all density does not just scale with the number of electrons. This is why we solve for them numerically.